# MSSQL Find if Column Value has change for same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, compare, analytics

I have the following Table:

```
 EMP_ID | Color | StartDate  | EndDate
------------------------------------------
 1      | Black | 01/01/2010 | 01/01/2011
 1      | Black | 01/01/2012 | 01/01/2013
 1      | Green | 01/01/2014 | 01/01/2015
 2      | Black | 01/01/2010 | 01/01/2011
 2      | White | 01/01/2012 | 01/01/2013
 2      | Black | 01/01/2014 | 01/01/2015
 2      | Black | 01/01/2015 | 01/01/2016
```

What I am attempting to do is out of the `EMP_ID` Column values if the color changed at all when and what did it change to and group it by `EMP_ID`'s any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier using the `lag()` function in more recent versions of SQL.  There is a method using `outer apply`:

```
select t.*
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.emp_id = t.emp_id and t2.startdate < t.startdate
      order by t2.startdate desc
     ) tprev
where tprev is null or tprev.color <> t.color
```